# End location of the word from words array is not correct

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement a word search in a grid of letters and a list of words. The program should be able to find each word in the grid and display the start and end coordinates.  The words can go in all 8 directions. I am able to get the correct start coordinates however the end coordinates does not match for some of the words.

```
enter code here 

using System;
```

using System.Data;

namespace WordSearch
{
class Program
{
static int R, C;

```
    // For searching in all 8 direction
    static int[] x = { -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 };
    static int[] y = { -1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1 };
    static char[,] Grid = new char[,] {
        {'C', 'P', 'K', 'X', 'O', 'I', 'G', 'H', 'S', 'F', 'C', 'H'},
        {'Y', 'G', 'W', 'R', 'I', 'A', 'H', 'C', 'Q', 'R', 'X', 'K'},
        {'M', 'A', 'X', 'I', 'M', 'I', 'Z', 'A', 'T', 'I', 'O', 'N'},
        {'E', 'T', 'W', 'Z', 'N', 'L', 'W', 'G', 'E', 'D', 'Y', 'W'},
        {'M', 'C', 'L', 'E', 'L', 'D', 'N', 'V', 'L', 'G', 'P', 'T'},
        {'O', 'J', 'A', 'A', 'V', 'I', 'O', 'T', 'E', 'E', 'P', 'X'},
        {'C', 'D', 'B', 'P', 'H', 'I', 'A', 'W', 'V', 'X', 'U', 'I'},
        {'L', 'G', 'O', 'S', 'S', 'B', 'R', 'Q', 'I', 'A', 'P', 'K'},
        {'E', 'O', 'I', 'G', 'L', 'P', 'S', 'D', 'S', 'F', 'W', 'P'},
        {'W', 'F', 'K', 'E', 'G', 'O', 'L', 'F', 'I', 'F', 'R', 'S'},
        {'O', 'T', 'R', 'U', 'O', 'C', 'D', 'O', 'O', 'F', 'T', 'P'},
        {'C', 'A', 'R', 'P', 'E', 'T', 'R', 'W', 'N', 'G', 'V', 'Z'}
    };

    static string[] Words = new string[] 
    {
        "CARPET",
        "CHAIR",
        "DOG",
        "BALL",
        "DRIVEWAY",
        "FISHING",
        "FOODCOURT",
        "FRIDGE",
        "GOLF",
        "MAXIMIZATION",
        "PUPPY",
        "SPACE",
        "TABLE",
        "TELEVISION",
        "WELCOME",
        "WINDOW"
    };

    // This function searches in all 8-direction
    // from point (row, col) in grid[, ]
    static bool search2D(char[,] Grid, int row,
                         int col, String word)
    {
        // If first character of word doesn't match
        // with given starting point in grid.
        if (Grid[row, col] != word[0])
        {
            return false;
        }

        int len = word.Length;

        // Search word in all 8 directions
        // starting from (row, col)
        for (int dir = 0; dir < 8; dir++)
        {
            // Initialize starting point
            // for current direction
            int k, rd = row + x[dir], cd = col + y[dir];

            // First character is already checked,
            // match remaining characters
            for (k = 1; k < len; k++)
            {
                // If out of bound break
                if (rd >= R || rd < 0 || cd >= C || cd < 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                // If not matched, break
                if (Grid[rd, cd] != word[k])
                {
                    break;
                }

                // Moving in particular direction
                rd += x[dir];
                cd += y[dir];
            }

            // If all character matched, then value of k
            // must be equal to length of word
            if (k == len)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Searches given word in a given
    // matrix in all 8 directions
    static void patternSearch(char[,] Grid,
                              String word)
    {
        // Consider every point as starting
        // point and search given word
        for (int row = 0; row < R; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < C; col++)
            {
                if (search2D(Grid, row, col, word))
                {
                    int endposTest = word.IndexOf(word[word.Length - 1]) -1;
                    Console.WriteLine(word + "" + " found at (" + col + "," + row + ") to (" + col + "," + endposTest + ")");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        R = 12;
        C = 12;
        Console.WriteLine("Word Search");

        for (int y = 0; y < 12; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++)
            {
                Console.Write(Grid[y, x]);
                Console.Write(' ');
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");

        }

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Found Words");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");

        //foreach (string word in Words)
        //{
        //    patternSearch(Grid, word);
        //    Console.WriteLine();
        //}

        FindWords();

        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void FindWords()
    {
        foreach (string word in Words)
        {
            patternSearch(Grid, word);
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
        
    }
}
```

}

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u55p3.png)

Comment: What issue are you having, please clarify by updating your post.

Comment: here is a quick review. I will also not implement all direction at the same time and not provide grid of letter. I will make a grid of `-` and put only one word for each direction . And I will only test one direction at a time. This should narrow down your issue and produce a nice [mre] Or anything that allow quick comprehension and test like a grid 3x3 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}. That way every word are different and quite simple to see. and I will be testing word near the border at the same time.

Comment: Thanks Self 21 I will the solution using this approach.

Comment: Thanks Codexer. The issue is that end coordinates that I am getting in the output for each word are not correct. I have added an image for current output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only problem is that you are not taking into account the resulting direction when displaying the results. Just apply the following changes:

```cs
 static bool search2D(char[,] Grid, int row, int col, String word, out int wordDir) //add out parameter wordDir
 {
     wordDir = 0; //Initialize WordDir

   //[...]
```

```cs
  //[...]
       if (k == len)
       {
            wordDir = dir;   //Assign value to wordDir when solution is found
            return true;
       }
  //[...]
```

```cs
      //[...]
       int dir;
       if (search2D(Grid, row, col, word, out dir))
       {
          int lastRowIndex = row + x[dir] * (word.Length - 1); //calculate the actual final coords
          int lastColIndex = col + y[dir] * (word.Length - 1);

          Trace.WriteLine(word + "" + " found at (" + col + "," + row + ") to (" + lastColIndex + "," + lastRowIndex + ")");
        }
                        }
      //[...]
```

Comment: Thanks Amo Robb, I am able to get the end coordinates using the changes.